# Behavior of passed subplot reference different in direct reference and as list

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, pass-by-reference

I am trying to write a function to update a matplotlib chart following a combobox selection.  I don't understand a difference in behavior.  In the full program and in the streamlined version below, I create a subplot "a" and can pass it to a function ("tester") and it will modify the subplots attributes as expected.  But if I pass the subplot as an entry in a lambda function to a Comboboxselected entry, it does not work.  Why the difference?

When the following is run, the x-axis of the plot reads "XAXIS RESET BY TESTER", as expected given the call to tester().  When a new combobox entry is selected, update_chart() prints the choice in the combobox correctly, prints the accompanying test parameter "ZERO" correctly, but the x-axis on the chart does not change.  Why the difference in behaviors?

The following stand-alone code reproduces the problem:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg,
                                               NavigationToolbar2TkAgg)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

def make_chart_page(nb, chartPage):
    labelFrameChart = tk.LabelFrame(chartPage, text="Chart control:")
    labelFrameChart.pack(side="left", fill="y", padx=5, pady=5)
    comboChart = ttk.Combobox(labelFrameChart, values=["Foos", "Bars", "Widgets"], width=25)
    comboChart.pack(anchor="w", padx=5)
    f = Figure(figsize=(7,5), dpi=100)
    a = f.add_subplot(111)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, chartPage)
    canvas.show()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    data = [ "ZERO", a ]
    comboChart.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda event, args=data: callback(event, args))

    tester(a)

def tester(a):
    a.set_xlabel("XAXIS RESET BY TESTER")

def update_chart(combo, var0, chart):
    print ("Combobox choice is: ", combo)
    print ("Args[0] is: ", var0)
    chart.set_xlabel("Xaxis reset by Update_Chart")

def callback(eventObject, args):
    update_chart(eventObject.widget.get(), args[0], args[1])

def demo():
    root = tk.Tk()
    nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
    chartPage = ttk.Frame(nb)

    make_chart_page(nb, chartPage)

    nb.add(chartPage, text='Charts')
    nb.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo()
```

Thank you,
Randy

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to redraw the canvas again by calling `canvas.draw_idle()`.

```
def make_chart_page(nb, chartPage):
    ...
    global canvas
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, chartPage)
    ...

def update_chart(combo, var0, chart):
    print("Combobox choice is: ", combo)
    print("Args[0] is: ", var0)
    chart.set_xlabel("Xaxis reset by Update_Chart")
    canvas.draw_idle()
```

Comment: For updates within the event loop, always use `draw_idle()` instead of `draw()` to avoid temporary freezing. I corrected the code above.